# Is it good practice to use bucket items with Children?

Tags: buckets

I need to be able to build a navigation component, using items that are under a bucket.
There is a requirement in which the navigation would require different levels of nesting.

[image: Current Bucket Structure]

I was wondering if it's feasible or good to practice to allow editors to nest the items in a bucket, so to create something like the below:

[image: Nested Bucket structure]

Or would it be better to use a field defined on the page template itself to just link to the respective pages and hierarchy from there, without tampering with the current structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore allows you to specify a locked relationship between parent and child items that are stored in a bucket, so it lends credence to this idea being acceptable:

[image: lock child relationship]

You just need to be sure that this is configured properly and ensure that any possible item that may be created as a nested item within the bucket has this property set to true (where applicable).

When it comes to adding advanced functionality in buckets, whether a feature is good practice or not comes down to two factors:

1. Does it produce quirky side effects?
2. Can content authors easily understand / navigate / edit? It is crucial to understand your client.

It's worth noting that by default, bucketed items are actually hidden from view, and in its simplest implementation, bucket items are meant to be added from the top level (bucket) item, and bucketed items are meant to be found via search rather than manually drilling down. That said, when bucket functionality was first released, the concept of nested datasource items was less prevalent.

As a final point, think hard about whether a bucket is truly necessary the first place. Good old manual folder creation is easy for content authors to understand. So long as you don't have thousands of child items under a single node, the manual approach is rock solid.

Comment: Yes excellent points Marcel, it makes  sense and I will of course have a think about those points . I will of course verify if there are any quirks for this usage. Knowing the client, step by step ease of use has been essential. which is a big reason for raising this question.